# How to send data from my database to the google chart api in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am still new in laravel and I am using google chart API but do not know how to send data from my database.

Here is my controller Admin controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Role;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::all();

        $data = DB::table('animals')->select(
            DB::raw('type as type'),
            DB::raw('count(*) as number')
            );
        return view('admin.index', compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::query()->findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin.show', compact('user'));
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
    }
}
```

And I would like to send data to my admin/index. I am using template inheritance for this one that is why it looks incomplete

```
<center>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'Animal Slaughtered'],
                ['Cow',     5],
                ['Goat',      2],
                ['Chicken',  3],
                ['Pork', 2],
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Animal Slaughtered',
                is3D: true,
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</center>
```

Any help will be kindly welcomed as I have been on this since morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already sending `$user` to your view in this line:

```
return view('admin.index', compact('user'));
```

If you want to send `$data` too, all you have to do is this:

```
return view('admin.index', compact('user', 'data'));
```

Once in your view, both variables are accesible like this:

```
@php
    var_dump($user, $data);
@endphp
```

By the way, right now `$data` is just a query builder. You have to user the `get()` method to have a collection:

```
$data = DB::table('animals')->select(
                DB::raw('type as type'),
                DB::raw('count(*) as number')
            )->get();
```